# Trying to draw an stacked area plot with 20+ series

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, visualization

I have a dataset of approximately 1300 rows that keeps track of the number of monthly logins per user signup month, every month, and I'm trying to graph a stacked area chart with each series/trace being the user signup month.

The dataset looks like the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user signup month | login month | monthly login count | cumulative login count

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01           | 2016-01     |  50                 | 50
2016-01           | 2016-02     |  25                 | 75
2016-01           | 2016-03     |  15                 | 90
...
2019-05           | 2019-05     | 1000                | 1000
2019-05           | 2019-06     | 500                 | 1500
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is when I try to graph it in my python notebook, using

```
x=data['login_month']
y=data['cumulative_login_count']

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.stackplot(x,y, labels=['user_signup_month'])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

it shows up as one series, and not one series *per* distinct user signup month as desired. 
[image]

example of expected result: 
[image]

The examples that I have googled all manually enter in the series data, for example:

```
data={'A': [-378, -2347, 509, 987, 513], 
                        'B': [-527, -2599, 765, 533, 670], 
                        'C': [-2343, -2273, 2093, 2197, 1990], 
                        'D': [-1845, -1853, 3325, 1306, 2160]}
```

which is impractical and unsustainable for me to do.

I'm also fairly new to python visualization, so I'm not quite sure what search terms are most effective, but I have found the results of "python matlibplot multiple series traces stackedplot" to only reference the above solution with manually entered series data

Comment: What exactly do you expect your `x` and `y` axis represent?

Comment: @QuangHoang the x-axis is the month in which users login in. the y-axis is the number of cumulative logins over time. the multiples series are the month in which users sign up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and should always, try to give and example of your data. It doesn't need to be full, but representative. For example:

```
    signup    login  log_count
0  2016-01  2016-02         16
1  2016-01  2016-03         11
2  2016-01  2016-04         26
3  2016-01  2016-05         29
4  2016-02  2016-03         25
5  2016-02  2016-04         11
6  2016-02  2016-05         11
7  2016-03  2016-04         28
8  2016-03  2016-05         23
9  2016-04  2016-05         12
```

Now, with this toy data, we can produce area/stack plot by:

```
(df.pivot(index='login', 
          columns='signup', 
          values='log_count')
   .plot.area(figsize=(10,6))
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much quang! i thought the example data i was working with was illustrative enough, but i will make sure to make it more clear in the future!